# Is there a simpler way to parse the xml file into a nested array?

Tags: python, xml, multidimensional-array, beautifulsoup

Given an input file, e.g.

```
<srcset setid="newstest2015" srclang="any">
<doc sysid="ref" docid="1012-bbc" genre="news" origlang="en">
<p>
<seg id="1">India and Japan prime ministers meet in Tokyo</seg>
<seg id="2">India's new prime minister, Narendra Modi, is meeting his Japanese counterpart, Shinzo Abe, in Tokyo to discuss economic and security ties, on his first major foreign visit since winning May's election.</seg>
<seg id="3">Mr Modi is on a five-day trip to Japan to strengthen economic ties with the third largest economy in the world.</seg>
<seg id="4">High on the agenda are plans for greater nuclear co-operation.</seg>
<seg id="5">India is also reportedly hoping for a deal on defence collaboration between the two nations.</seg>
</p>
</doc>
<doc sysid="ref" docid="1018-lenta.ru" genre="news" origlang="ru">
<p>
<seg id="1">FANO Russia will hold a final Expert Session</seg>
<seg id="2">The Federal Agency of Scientific Organizations (FANO Russia), in joint cooperation with RAS, will hold the third Expert Session on “Evaluating the effectiveness of activities of scientific organizations”.</seg>
<seg id="3">The gathering will be the final one in a series of meetings held by the agency over the course of the year, reports a press release delivered to the editorial offices of Lenta.ru.</seg>
<seg id="4">At the third meeting, it is planned that the results of the work conducted by the Expert Session over the past year will be presented and that a final checklist to evaluate the effectiveness of scientific organizations will be developed.</seg>
</p>
</doc>
<srcset>
```

The desired result is a nested dictionary that stores:

```
/setid
    /docid
        /segid
            text
```

I've been using a defaultdict and reading the xml file with BeautifulSoup and nested loops, i.e.

```
from io import StringIO
from collections import defaultdict

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

srcfile = """<srcset setid="newstest2015" srclang="any">
<doc sysid="ref" docid="1012-bbc" genre="news" origlang="en">
<p>
<seg id="1">India and Japan prime ministers meet in Tokyo</seg>
<seg id="2">India's new prime minister, Narendra Modi, is meeting his Japanese counterpart, Shinzo Abe, in Tokyo to discuss economic and security ties, on his first major foreign visit since winning May's election.</seg>
<seg id="3">Mr Modi is on a five-day trip to Japan to strengthen economic ties with the third largest economy in the world.</seg>
<seg id="4">High on the agenda are plans for greater nuclear co-operation.</seg>
<seg id="5">India is also reportedly hoping for a deal on defence collaboration between the two nations.</seg>
</p>
</doc>
<doc sysid="ref" docid="1018-lenta.ru" genre="news" origlang="ru">
<p>
<seg id="1">FANO Russia will hold a final Expert Session</seg>
<seg id="2">The Federal Agency of Scientific Organizations (FANO Russia), in joint cooperation with RAS, will hold the third Expert Session on “Evaluating the effectiveness of activities of scientific organizations”.</seg>
<seg id="3">The gathering will be the final one in a series of meetings held by the agency over the course of the year, reports a press release delivered to the editorial offices of Lenta.ru.</seg>
<seg id="4">At the third meeting, it is planned that the results of the work conducted by the Expert Session over the past year will be presented and that a final checklist to evaluate the effectiveness of scientific organizations will be developed.</seg>
</p>
</doc>
<srcset>"""

#ntok = NISTTokenizer()

eval_docs = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))

with StringIO(srcfile) as fin:
    bsoup = BeautifulSoup(fin.read(), 'html5lib')
    setid = bsoup.find('srcset')['setid']
    for doc in bsoup.find_all('doc'):
        docid = doc['docid']
        for seg in doc.find_all('seg'):
            segid = seg['id']
            eval_docs[setid][docid][segid] = seg.text
```

[out]:

```
>>> eval_docs

defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'newstest2015': defaultdict(dict,
                         {'1012-bbc': {'1': 'India and Japan prime ministers meet in Tokyo',
                           '2': "India's new prime minister, Narendra Modi, is meeting his Japanese counterpart, Shinzo Abe, in Tokyo to discuss economic and security ties, on his first major foreign visit since winning May's election.",
                           '3': 'Mr Modi is on a five-day trip to Japan to strengthen economic ties with the third largest economy in the world.',
                           '4': 'High on the agenda are plans for greater nuclear co-operation.',
                           '5': 'India is also reportedly hoping for a deal on defence collaboration between the two nations.'},
                          '1018-lenta.ru': {'1': 'FANO Russia will hold a final Expert Session',
                           '2': 'The Federal Agency of Scientific Organizations (FANO Russia), in joint cooperation with RAS, will hold the third Expert Session on “Evaluating the effectiveness of activities of scientific organizations”.',
                           '3': 'The gathering will be the final one in a series of meetings held by the agency over the course of the year, reports a press release delivered to the editorial offices of Lenta.ru.',
                           '4': 'At the third meeting, it is planned that the results of the work conducted by the Expert Session over the past year will be presented and that a final checklist to evaluate the effectiveness of scientific organizations will be developed.'}})})
```

**Is there a simpler way to read the file and get the same `eval_docs` nested dictionary?**

**Can it be done easily without using `BeautifulSoup`?**

Note that in the example, there's only one `setid` and one `docid` but the actual file has more than one of those.

Comment: Are you looking for `xmltodict` lib?

Comment: I personally think that the current solution is pretty good and readable. You may probably improve on speed (if this is a concern at all here) if using `lxml` directly. You may also look into `xmltodict` module..but your output dictionary is a "custom-made" one and the keys are coming from different attributes..not sure you would improve your current solution by switching to `xmltodict`..

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation on `xmltodict`! Cool, I've never knew about that.

Comment: Ah but it looks like `xmltodict` requires a well-form xml but my input is some custom xml like structure that is consistent but not following strict xml rules. I.e. http://data.statmt.org/wmt17/translation-task/wmt17-submitted-data-v1.0.tgz

Comment: Right, then putting it through `BeautifulSoup` would make perfect sense,  it is quite good at dealing with non-well-formed XML/HTML inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since what you have is an HTML with an appearance like XML, you can't go for XML based tools. In most cases your options were

- Implement SAX parser
- use BS4 (which you are already doing)
- Use lxml

In any case you will end up spending more time and effort and have a bigger code to handle this. What you have really sleek and easy. I wouldn't look for another solution if I was you.

PS: What simpler could it be than a 10 liner code!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you'll find this simpler, but here's an alternative, using `lxml` as others have suggested.

**Step 1:** Convert the XML data into a normalized table (a list of lists)

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('source.xml')
segs = tree.xpath('//seg')

normalized_list = []
for seg in segs:
    srcset = seg.getparent().getparent().getparent().attrib['setid']
    doc = seg.getparent().getparent().attrib['docid']
    normalized_list.append([srcset, doc, seg.attrib['id'], seg.text])
```

**Step 2:** Use `defaultdict` like you did in your original code

```
d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(dict))
for i in normalized_list:
    d[i[0]][i[1]][i[2]] = i[3]
```

Depending on how you're keeping the source file, you'll have to use one of these methods to parse XML:

- `tree = etree.parse('source.xml')`: when you want to parse a file directly - you won't need `StringIO`. File is closed automatically by `etree`.
- `tree = etree.fromstring(source)`: where `source` is a string object, like in your question.